# HSQLDB - hiding database structure/contents from users

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm considering using HSQLDB version 1.8.x in a desktop app for storing local data.  From what I can see, the database is stored on disk as a number of SQL statements to create the tables, insert the data, etc.

Is there a simple way I can hide this from users? I'm don't necessarily need it to be completely encrypted, etc - I'd just like to prevent the casual user from simply opening the file and seeing the structure of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've gone with for now is to call:

```
db.update("SET SCRIPTFORMAT COMPRESSED;");
```

to store the .script file in a human-unreadable form and:

```
db.update("SET PASSWORD password;");
```

to prevent more savvy users from opening the DB using their own HSQLDB client.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed your database files within a jar file and connect to them using the notation:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:res:<path in jar>
```

Check out the [Advanced Topics](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html) section of the HSQLDB guide for more information on this.  However, I've never tried it so am not 100% sure it will work ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to execute below command
db.update("SET scriptformat COMPRESSED");

And was getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SCRIPTFORMAT
```

This error solved with this command
db.update("SET FILES SCRIPT FORMAT COMPRESSED");

I am using HSQLDB 2.3.3

Comment: The command in version 2.x is `SET FILES SCRIPT FORMAT COMPRESSED`